# How can I get all my papers under the same Scopus profile?

Tags: publications, personal-name, scopus

I have recently searched my publications in Scopus and I have found that they are all scattered around. The reason behind that maybe is because I have a compound last name. The situation has gone pretty weird also in one of my papers, where they have put one of my last names to another author that I do not even know.

The question that I have is how I can make to put all my papers under a same profile, and also delete that "ghost" author from one of my papers.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on "contact"? There's a function to suggest fixes to the database (missing citations, wrong titles, authors to merge, and so on).

Answer (score 5):

As Federico indicates, the [contact form](http://help.elsevier.com/app/ask_scopus/p/8150) (“Ask a question”) has a field for suggesting correction to the index:

[image]

You can directly send them the papers in question:

> Please attach a copy of the missing or incorrect document, this is essential for us to verify the changes and make the corrections.

While I don't have any direct experience with Scopus in that area, they are generally serious and I think they will act on your request. I have once contact another index provider (Web of Science) with a correction, and they updated the data within a week.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way would be to "request to merge".
Let's say that both 2 and 3 in the attached screenshots are you. Just mark the checkmark and click the "Request to merge" link.
You might want to click "Show Profile Matches with One Document" before you look up all of your entries.
[image]